# How can I reference a 3D array from another class?

Tags: c#, class, multidimensional-array, reference, program-entry-point

In the main program class I have:

```
 static void Main()
 {
    string[,,] anArray = new string [3,3,3];
        anArray[0,0,0] = "value1";
        anArray[0,0,1] = "value2"; .... //filling the rest of the array.
 }
```

How can I pass this array into another separate class "anotherClass" using a constructor with multiple arguments like:

```
 class AnotherClass
 {
 private string[,,] anotherClassArray;

 public string[,,] AnotherClassArray
 {
     get { return anotherClassArray;}
 }

 public AnotherClass (string[,,] fromAnArray)
 {
    anotherClassArray = new string [fromAnArray.Length];
 }
 }
```

I've seen examples with just a simple 1 dimensional array being passed from the Main program into another separate class and back again but when I tried following the same example for a multidimensional I get the error:

"Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'string[*,*,*]'" when trying to initialize the new array.

Comment: What do you want to do? Just initializing `anotherClassArray` reference or a local copy of 3d array??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want AnotherClass to have it's own separate, empty, instance of a 3D array, then you can do what Pikoh said. In this case, if you change the contents of the array, the original array created in Main is unaffected, and vice versa.

If you want AnotherClass to reference the same array as the one created in Main, and therefor have access to it's same, filled in contents, then simply set the AnotherClass.anotherClassArray reference to equal fromAnArray in the AnotherClass constructor like so:

```
public AnotherClass (string[,,] fromAnArray)
{
   anotherClassArray = fromAnArray;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!, Although Pikoh explained it more clearly for me, your method was actually the one I needed for this code.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
string[, ,] anotherClassArray = new string[anArray.GetLength(0),
                                           anArray.GetLength(1),
                                           anArray.GetLength(2)];
```

**Update**

As a experiment, if you want make this to generic for any unknown number of dimensions, you can use this method:

```
private Array CreateArrayWithSameDimensions(Array inArray)
{
    int[] lengths = new int[inArray.Rank];
    for (int i = 0; i < inArray.Rank; i++)
    {
        lengths[i] = inArray.GetLength(i);
    }
    Array myArray = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(string), lengths);
    return myArray;
}
```

The problem with this approach is that accessing this array is not as simple as with known dimensions. This is an example of usage:

```
Array myArray = CreateArrayWithSameDimensions(anArray);
int[] indices = new int[anArray.Rank];

for (int i = 0; i < anArray.Rank; i++)
{
       indices[i] = 0;
}

myArray.SetValue("test", indices);
```

This would set `test` in the lower bound index of that array. If the input array was a 3 dimensional array, in myArray[0,0,0] we would have `test`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation -- it really helped me learn about referencing multidimensional arrays.  Although it worked when I tried it out, it wasn't quite what I was looking for but I will keep this answer in mind because I can definitely see it being useful to implement in a future code when needed.  Thanks again!